# How to override md-autocomplete scss in angular 4?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have created an app where I have used md-autocomplete from material.angular.io.

Now problem comes when I am trying to search anything , the dropdown of suggestions has less width. So I want to increase the width of md-autocomplete.

I have tried overriding scss, inline scss but no use.

Below is my code.

```
<div class="fill-remaining-space">
  <md-input-container class="example-full-width" color="accent">
    <md-icon mdPrefix>search</md-icon>
    <input type="text" mdInput [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="searchCtrl">
    <md-icon mdSuffix (click)="clear()">clear</md-icon>
  </md-input-container>
  <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" id="autocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let result of filteredResults" [value]="result.name">
      <span [routerLink]="['/category',result.type]" class="row"> {{result.name | lowercase}}<span>&nbsp; in &nbsp;<span class="type"> {{result.type}} </span></span>
      </span>
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>
</div>
```

I am trying to override this scss using:

```
.fill-remaining-space {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 9px;
    margin-left: 14%;
    width: 74%;
    .mat-autocomplete-panel.mat-autocomplete-visible /deep/ {
      background-color: blue !important;
    }
  }
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do it is to set the [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) to None on your component:

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './my.component.html' ,
    styleUrls: ['./my.component.css'], 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Then in your component css you can do exactly what you tried:

```
.mat-autocomplete-panel.mat-autocomplete-visible {
      background-color: blue !important;
    }
```

> View Encapsulation = None means that Angular does no view
>   encapsulation. Angular adds the CSS to the global styles. The scoping
>   rules, isolations, and protections discussed earlier don't apply. This
>   is essentially the same as pasting the component's styles into the
>   HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I just added this to the global styles:

```
.mat-autocomplete-panel {
    width: 30rem;
}
```

[See plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bwQbOqHNAACgIhThDu4T?p=preview) (the global styles are here the style tags in index.html)

Comment: Keep in mind that this will affect _all_ autocompletes in your application. Currently there is no good way to target specific autocomplete components, but https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/6618 will add that support.